# JCrop zebra pattern on cropping window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm using jquery jcrop, recently I've been seeing a weird pattern on the cropping window. I'm not sure what it is exactly.

[image]

Why is there a zebra pattern on the cropping window. What does it signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of Jcrop. It appears that something is making the bottom border line taller than one pixel. You are seeing the animated GIF background graphic that is used to give the appearance of "antlines". I can't tell what is causing this without more information, but I'm guessing it's something to do with other CSS that is loaded on your page.

Comment: Yes you were right! There was a `.top` from datatables in my code with 15px padding. It was just strange (because it was animated too!, it looked very intentionally designed)